# How to make dojo.request.xhr GET request with basic authentication

Tags: https, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I look at the documentation for [Dojo v.1.9 request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr)
and I cannot find example that includes basic authentication.

How and where do I include the User name and Password in the Dojo XHR options?

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr){
  xhr("example.json", {
    // Include User and Password options here ?
    user: "userLogin"
    password: "userPassword"
    handleAs: "json"
  }).then(function(data){
    // Do something with the handled data
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  }, function(evt){
    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
    // browser supports XHR2
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, you should be able to pass the user and password with the `user` and `password` property in the `options` object.

In previous versions of Dojo this was documented, but it seems that now they aren't. However, I just tested it and it seems to add the username and password to the URL, like:

```
http://user:password@myUrl/example.json
```

Normally the browser should be capable of translating this URL so the request headers are set.

---

You could also set these headers manually, for example by using:

```
xhr("example.json", {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encode(toByteArray(user + ":" + pass))
    }
}).then(function(data) {
    // Do something 
});
```

However, this requires the `dojox/encoding/base64` module and the following function:

```
var toByteArray = function(str) {
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return bytes;
};
```